# Cannot connect to Jetty Websocket Server running on AWS Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, jetty, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I am currently trying to connect to a websocket server running on my environment in AWS Cloud9. The server is in Java using Jetty. It works perfectly fine running on my computer and on a raspberry pi. The client in AWS Cloud9 can successfully connect to my pi server but not the one running in AWS cloud9. The client is a simple React App with the node.js server running on port 8080 and the websocket server on port 8081. When I connect to my environment url port 8080 the client successfully loads but when I try to connect to my weboscket server via the ws protocol on port 8081 the console tells me that a connection cannot be established. I have ensured that the weboscket server is running on cloud9. Showing active servers in cloud9 reveals the server is indeed running on port 8081. Also, the error isn't in the websocket server being unsecured because I can connect to the same server running on a pi.

This is the client code portion (account and region removed):

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://MYACCOUNT.vfs.cloud9.MYREGION.amazonaws.com:8081");
```

and the error is this:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://MYACCOUNT.vfs.cloud9.MYREGION.amazonaws.com:8081/.
```

Comment: You'll need to know a lot more about your AWS setup, [some features of AWS do not support WebSocket](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+websocket+site%3Astackoverflow.com).